# How to integrate Payfort payment gateway in angular 8 or in Node Js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular7, angular8, payfort

I want to integrate **payfort** payment gateway in angular or node app. I have read documentation but couldn't find much about javascript (angular / node). I have searched for examples but couldn't find any. So anyone could help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

Officially no support in nodejs

Get the github from here [payfort github](https://github.com/payfort)